# How to know which implementation of memcpy will be used in glibc?

Tags: gcc, glibc, memcpy

A basic call to `memcpy` from a C/C++ program can be mapped to different implementations by the glibc depending on the type of cpu, the cpu's feaures, the compiler options, etc.

For instance, it can use cpu-optimized implementation for Intel, NEON, SSE support...

Is it possible to know which implementation will be used *without* actually running the piece of software calling `memcpy`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to know which implementation will be used without actually running the piece of software calling memcpy?

Yes: you need to trace through the logic of `memcpy` `IFUNC` selector, and know which features your CPU does and doesn't have. In other words, you'll need to "run" the program on an emulator (your head, paper, etc.).

For most people, actually running the program on a given CPU is much faster, and gives a guaranteed correct answer.

Note also that the answer may change depending on the version of GLIBC.